# Hook into linux authentication to run script or program when certain conditions are met

Tags: linux, security, authentication, encryption

Using ecryptfs or encfs (Possibly more) the actual decryption passphrase is kept in a file that is decrypted by the password.

Because of this, if paranoid (Or trying to impress) you can effectively shred all the encrypted data to US DOD standards (Usually the entire home directory) in a few milliseconds.

I want to setup my computer (Or at least my vbox system) to shred the wrapped passphrase if a specific password is entered, or the wrong password is entered a certain amount of times in a row.

This would be easy enough but I don't know how to get into the linux authentication system at a level that will allow me to check the incorrect password and/or run the shred program on the file.

TL;DR: Anyone know how to make linux shred a file if an incorrect login used a specific password?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, the method to use to hook into Linux authentication is via [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_PAM). Either writing your own PAM module, or by finding one that can be coerced into doing what you want.

The easiest option I can see is [pam_script](http://freshmeat.net/projects/pam_script/).

Install, then put `auth optional pam_script.so` in the appropriate file(s) in /etc/pam.d and write a pam_script_auth script that looks at $PAM_USER and $PAM_AUTHTOK.

Note that the script could be run as root or as the user, so storage of the password failure data needs to be done with careful attention to permissions.

The simple version without the multiple failures version is somewhat like:

```
if [ $PAM_USER = "jv" ] && [ $PAM_AUTHTOK = "ThePoliceHaveMe" ]; then
  shredcommand
fi
```

Comment: I think I know what you mean, add a line with `pam_script.so` to `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` (Or can I make something else specifically for my user? `cp /etc/pam.d/common-auth /etc/pam.d/$USER-auth`?) then write a script to handle it? Only problem being that I don't know how exactly to do either of these.

Comment: /etc/pam.d/$USER-auth won't work, everything in /etc/pam.d is selecting based on what program is asking, not who you are. I added a simple example script to my answer, but I don't know what commands to run to shred the password.

Comment: Ooh wow this is a blast from the past. I did as a matter of fact. 4 and a half years later it looks like programminghorror to me, but I'll stick it up if you want it

Comment: @JV can I see your final working example? I'm getting stuck on easy obstacles

Answer (score 5):

Good answers have already been posted explaining how to do what you want to do using the Pluggable Authentication Modules so I won't repeat them.

#### Three things to keep in mind:

First, when you automatically shred your encryption keys after a certain number of failed logins then you have a nasty denial of service vulnerability, where anyone can destroy all of your data by just repeatedly logging in incorrectly.

Second, you probably think that it would work when "they" get your machine but it wouldn't, because while trying to break your encryption or guess your password no one would use **your** system to do it. The first thing anyone would do is to copy your raw partitions and play with your data in a safe environment where they can be sure that the data they are trying to read won't get destroyed in the process.

Third, as for shredding the whole data to US DOD standards in a few milliseconds, remember to also shred the entire swap partition, or to not use one in the first place. Also, while it may seem not needed, remember to shred the contents of RAM as well, because the contents of RAM can sometimes be recovered even after power loss.

Comment: I would just zip the file and cat it onto an image at some random place on the internet to recover. It's mainly an exercise but would help if someone without computer skills is threatening you to give them the password right then and there. If you are using an encrypted folder you should be using a random `dm-crypt`ed swap anyway, and ram doesn't persist for nearly as long as necessary to recover data without liquid nitrogen and if they use that they probably had a hardware keylogger anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to develop a [PAM module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_Authentication_Modules) and configure your system to use this for password validation.

If this is a bit daunting, you could try [PAM-script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pam-script/) which claims the ability to run scripts as part of the authentication process. I've not tried this myself.

Comment: That's what I was told but firstly there are pam modules that let you run python or php "Modules" and secondly, I haven't got a clue how to make a full blown PAM module. There don't seem to be any tutorials out there (Makes sense as most people messing with this stuff would probably know everything already)